# WPF contextmenu binding

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

Cant seem to bind a menuitem in my contextmenu to a command in my viewmodel. I know the contextmenu does not live in the visual tree. For testing purposes i have bound to the same command twice in a button. The first binding works but i can get the second binding in the contextmenu to bind. I can see the binding error in output. Someone has any idea?

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type inf:OSiteEquipment}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubSystems, Converter={StaticResource subsystemConverter}}"  >
                <Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandOpenSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}">

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PartData.Name}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
                    <Button.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>                                                                         

     <MenuItem Header="Add Category"  Command="{Binding Path=Parent.PlacementTarget.Tag.CommandOpenSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
                        </ContextMenu>

                    </Button.ContextMenu>
                </Button>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: can you give the binding error ?

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'TreeViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "Parent" in the Databinding path :

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type inf:OSiteEquipment}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubSystems, Converter={StaticResource subsystemConverter}}"  >
    <Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
            Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandOpenSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding}">

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PartData.Name}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Add Category"  Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault new error is. System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'CommandOpenSelected' property not found on 'object' ''Button' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=PlacementTarget.CommandOpenSelected; DataItem='ContextMenu' (Name=''); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way. That would work but im going to have additional commands eventually in the contextmenu so i still need to bind to the datacontext of the usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

1. You already find the `Parent` via the relative source -> Omit the `Parent` in the path
2. You did not even set the `Tag` on the `PlacementTarget` (`Button`) -> Set it respectively